# Let's Learn Big Numbers achievement not unlocking

Tags: steam, achievements, adventure-capitalist

I've got 62 Decillion on hand, and the game calls me a decillionaire, but the Steam Achievement hasn't unlocked. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet at the moment you play?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Yup, online on steam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I logged a ticket with the devs and they confirmed that this was a bug. Sadness!

Answer (score 3):

For me it triggered somewhere random, but most people get it around 10 decillion, something I can find in more places on the internet, for example [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/346900/discussions/0/530646080862336260/) or [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/346900/discussions/0/618463738386332776/):

> Just continue playing and you will get it. Some people reported getting it at 10 decillion, others at 100 and some after next reset. No one reported that they were not able to get it at all.

So just keep playing until you get it.

Comment: Well I'm currently on 40 undecillion on hand and it's still not triggered...!